# Is the permission - android.permission.INTERNET, specific to a particular type of internet connection (like 2G, 3G) ?

Tags: java, android, permissions

Is the permission - android.permission.INTERNET, specific to a particular type of internet connection (like 2G, 3G) or does it work across all types? And, do I require the INTERNET permission to communicate on a private network that does not have/need access to the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any Android device, if it has to communicate with another device, has to make use of [sockets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html). When you provide your application with the INTERNET permission, you are essentially requesting for [permission to open network sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET). So, no matter where the other device that you need to communicate with is on (2G, 3G internet, WiFi, LAN etc), you will need to use the INTERNET permission to open a socket to communicate with it.

Comment: Good explanation. Can I know if we communicate it with usb connection. Is it necessary to get permission through this method "android.permission.INTERNET"  for get access those ports?

Comment: A USB cable is just the medium through which you are communicating. Ultimately, if you have to communicate with another device via USB (or any other medium), you will need sockets. And so, you will need the INTERNET permission.

Comment: Scenario is like this. I need to communicate mobile app with desktop. I dont need internet access for my app. Also it's communicate with usb port. Because of that do I neet to give permission "android.permission.INTERNET"?

Comment: Here, the term INTERNET does not actually mean THE internet. Its a permission to create sockets - even for sockets that are not exactly connecting to devices over THE internet. So, yes, in order to communicate with your desktop, you will need the INTERNET permission.

Comment: I got your point. Another thing, is that "android.permission" mean we getting permission from whom?  Is that from user(inform and get permission) Or from the device(android kernel) that we are gonna open those sockets?

Comment: "If an application needs access to a feature protected by a permission, it must declare that it requires that permission in the manifest. Then, when the application is installed on the device, the installer determines whether or not to grant the requested permission by checking the authorities that signed the application's certificates and, in some cases, asking the user. If the permission is granted, the application is able to use the protected features. If not, its attempts to access those features will simply fail"-http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html#perms

Answer (score 5):

`android.permission.INTERNET` allows access to the internet over any medium (WiFi, Mobile). It's wise to be cautious about the user's usage limits though, and you should consider properly [managing network usage](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/managing.html).

Comment: Is there any kind of effect for  android intent?

Comment: I'm not to sure what you mean. Do you mean, can you launch a url without the permission?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this function to isolate them and to perform operation as per your requirements as well.

```
public  boolean isConnected()
        {

            boolean status = false;

            ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(this.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            Boolean is3g = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).isConnectedOrConnecting();
            Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();

                if(is3g){
                    status = true;

                }else if(isWifi){

                    status = true;

                }else{
                    startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS));
                }

            return status;
        }
```